# Include / extend modules in python

Tags: python, import, include

I don't now if this is the correct title for my question, I don't know how this is called in python specifically.

What I want is "simple".

I have a file 1.py which says:

```
x = 10
```

And I have another which is 2.py

```
print x
```

Which should print ten.

What I'm searching for is is the equivalente of `extends` in Java or or `include` in PHP.

Is this possible? Should I be including files or something else?

Thanks in advance!

<sub>I apologize if this question doesn't make perfect sense, I'll improve my question (if necessary) when I get an answer.
& I'm not 100% sure this is not a dupe since I do not know what I should be searching for.</sub>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about import?

```
from file1 import x
print x
```

Or:

```
import file1
print file1.x
```

The first imports x into the global namespace, the second imports file1's namespace.

This is not similar to `extends` in Java (it's actually very similar to `import` in Java), that would be accomplished using Python inheritance:

```
class Subclass:
    ...

class ExtendsSubclass(Subclass):
    ...
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for, but is there a way to import everything at once? lets say have lots of variables...

Comment: @Trufa: `from file1 import *`, but you really shouldn't ever use that because it can mess up the global namespace. Instead use `import file1` and each time you refer to a variable from file1 qualify it with the file1 namespace e.g. `file1.x`, `file1.y`, etc.

Comment: To reiterate, you really shouldn't `import *`. There are exceptions where it's valid, but they're rare and require some experience and good judgement to recognize, so generally you should treat this feature as non-existent. Read http://docs.python.org/howto/doanddont.html#from-module-import.